# Greatest common divisor of powers of $a,b$

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

> For all integers $a, b$ and nonnegative integers $m, n$, we have $\gcd(a^m, b^n ) = \gcd(a, b)^{\min(m,n)}$.

I have no idea where to go with this problem and how to even start it.

Comment: Try working with a factorization of $a$ and $b$ and see what happens as you take powers.

Comment: @Sajid I edited, do you see why?

Comment: @RossMillikan ok, done. I guess I don't know how to improve the post

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.  Take $a=8=2^3, b=4=2^2, m=2, n=3$.  Then $a^m=b^n=2^6$, so $\gcd(a^m,b^n)=2^6$, but $\gcd(a,b)^{\min(m,n)}=(2^2)^2=2^4$

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Ross Millikan, this is not true.

What is true is that if  $a = \prod_i {p_i^{\alpha_1}}$ and  $b= \prod_i {p_i^{\beta_1}}$ are the prime factorisation of a and b, then for $n,m \in \Bbb N$ :

$$gcd(a^n, b^m) = \prod_{i=1}^{+\infty} {p_i ^{\min (n \alpha_i, m \beta_i)}}$$

Thus your property only holds iff for $i \in \Bbb N$, you have $\alpha_i = 0$ or $\beta_i = 0$ or $\alpha_i = \beta_i$ (if I am not mistaken).

That is iff $a\over{gcd(a,b)}$ and $gcd(a,b)$ are relatively prime and $b\over{gcd(a,b)}$ and $gcd(a,b)$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I edited as per Ross' correction

Comment: You did not edit correctly : if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $gcd(a,b) = 1$ and thus the property is obvious !

Comment: How to edit then? Any suggestion welcome. I just wanted to make a false statement into a true. Please edit for improvement if you wish...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set up: Let $gcd(a,b)=x$, then we can write $a=px$ and $b=qx$. Now what is the gcd of $p$ and $q$? All right, move on. Let $a^m=p^mx^m$ and $b^n=q^nx^n$. Is it obvious what $p^m$ and $q^n$ have in common, which is not a whole lot? Ok, now for sure $x^m$ and $x^n$ do have something in common, right? Why would we be interested in the lowest exponent of the two? Because that answer will help you in the right hand side of the equation you need to prove.

Comment: But $p$ could have factors common with $x$.  See my example.

Comment: @RossMillikan. Ok, are you saying that the theorem to be proven is not really a theorem? Should $a$ and $b$ be relative prime then? Honestly, I did not think much to finish the prove because I wanted the OP to do that....

Comment: No, it is not a theorem.  Having $a$ and $b$ relatively prime would make it true, but not very interesting.  I don't see a way to patch up the statement to make it both true and interesting.

Comment: @RossMillikan. Right, understood, thanks (I edited, at least it isn't wrong anymore)